# How to automate recurring dates so as to automatically add one month after current date?[Python-Django]

Tags: python, django, django-models

Need help in automating recurring dates so as to automatically add one month after the current date?

Raw Example:
joining date: 2020/6/1
due_date:2020/7/1

Q1-> How to change the month of due date every month automatically
Q2-> How to set a current due amount by calculating the due + price - paid =?

My models.py:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    property_type = (
        ('Room', "Room"),
        ('PG', "PG"),
        ('Co-Living', "Co-Living"),
        ('1BHK', "1BHK"),
        ('2BHK', "2BHK"),
        ('3BHK', "3BHK"),
    )
    bath_type = (
        ('Attached Bath', "Attached-Bath"),
        ('Common Bath', "Common-Bath")
    )
    furnish_status = (
        ('Yes', "Yes"),
        ('No', "No")
    )

    payment_category = (
        ('Company', "Company"),
        ('Individual', "Individual")
    )

    due_status = (
        ('Due', "Due"),
        ('Paid', "Paid")
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    room_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bed_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    building_category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    property_type = models.CharField(choices=property_type, max_length=25)
    bath_type = models.CharField(choices=bath_type, max_length=25)
    furnish_status = models.CharField(choices=furnish_status, max_length=25)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    area = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    beds_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    floor_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='property/', null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    advance = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    paid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    due = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    due_status = models.CharField(choices=due_status, max_length=25)

    joined_date = models.DateField()
    due_date = models.DateField()

    tenant_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tenant_number = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    payment_category = models.CharField(choices=payment_category, max_length=25)

    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug and self.bed_id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.bed_id)
        super(Property, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Property'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Properties'
```

Let me know if you need to know anything else...

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to check this right now and I am not sure if I get you right but from my opinion you could override the save function as you already did for your slug

first:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Then change your save function:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug and self.bed_id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.bed_id)
    if not self.due_date:
        self.due_date = datetime.now().date().replace(month=(datetime.now().month + 1))
    else:
        self.due_date = self.due_date.replace(self.due_date.month + 1)
    super(Property, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Does that work for you? Or do you need something else?

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but when I just tried saving today as due date and refreshed it, it did not work.

Comment: As which type are you trying to save the date? As String or as datetime object? Was there an error when you tried my approach?

Comment: Yes when i set due_date = today and save it, the date won't change automatically to next month.

Comment: Yeah but are you saving it as a date object like datetime.now().date() or as a string like "2020-07-17"?

Comment: I  am saving it manually in the Django admin section as DateField() as you can see in my models.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a function to add one month

```
import datetime
import calendar

def add_month(join_date):
    due_day = join_date.day
    due_month = join_date.month + 1 if join_date.month < 12 else 1
    due_year = join_date.year + 1 if due_month == 1 else join_date.year
    if due_day > calendar.mdays[due_month]:
        due_day = calendar.mdays[due_month]
        if due_year % 4 == 0 and due_month == 2:
            due_day += 1
    return datetime.date(due_year, due_month, due_day)
```

Then you can override your `save` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    .....
    current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
    self.due_date = add_month(self.due_date) if self.due_date.month != current_month else 
    self.due_date
    self.due_amount = self.due + self.price - self.paid
    ......
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer but the code is not getting accepted as day, month and year are not defined in the model Property and I don't know how to strip the date field to its components separately like Year, Day, and Month to assign it to a variable.

Comment: You don't need day, month and year defined in the model Property, Django `DateField` represented in Python by a datetime.date instance and you can get the day, the month and the year

Comment: When i try to add code in the 1st paragraph, it won't accept it as it says day, month is not defined.